# Call function inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of object and i want to filter this to between to date.

I write function for this if date is between to dates return true else return false.
This is my function.

```
private bool IsDateBetween(DateTime date, string min, string max) {
        bool resultMin = true;
        bool resultMax = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(min))
        {
            resultMin = date > Convert.ToDateTime(min);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(max)) {
            resultMax = date < Convert.ToDateTime(max);
        }
        return resultMin&&resultMax;
    }
```

and this is how i call function with linq.

```
var policiesT = policies.Where(x=>IsDateBetween(x.StartofInsurance,startDateS,startDateF));
```

startDateS and startDateF is string of datetime and i checked that values.

They have value when i run the code.
But problem is when i debug the function min and max values always coming null.
This is the image before the calling function
[image]
This is the image when function is running.
[image]
Why that values caming null can u helpp me. 
Thanks

Comment: are those min max strings part of the policy object, or are they declared somewhere else.

Comment: They are declared somewhere else. User select max and min date from form they are coming from there.

Comment: If you debug and they are null , then the problem is somewhere else

Comment: when ı run the linq line startDateS is not null it has value but when function is running min coming null. what could be a problem here.

Comment: are they also null if you run `policies.Where(x=>IsDateBetween(x.StartofInsurance,startDateS,startDateF)).ToArray()`, because then the values are out of scope

Comment: if you put a line above your LinQ, 
var test = startDateS;
what ends up in test?  If that is null, then the value startDateS is null outside of the Linq, so it would not be to do with LinQ

Comment: You are using Convert.ToDateTime() without any culure specification. Are you sure your strings are convertible to a valid DateTime?

Comment: i uploaded some photos can you check the question.

Comment: Pictures don't help really. There is no date there too. And why would you create such a function after all? You could do an inline DateTime.TryParse and between check (policies are IEnumerable right?)

Comment: I'm having a hard to tryng to discern how the before images prove they are not null ?

Comment: date is datetime object and has a value always not null.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I updated image sory the first one ı crop too much.

Comment: @DilshodK Yes  im using EF

Comment: Is it even going to translate? Or is this data already downloaded?

Comment: Smells like a race condition or data race

Comment: @TheGeneral How can i avoid that do you have suggestion.

Comment: That can only be answered by you providing a complete reproduction of the error so we can tell you why at time X something was null and was not null by the time you came to look at it at Y

Comment: @SadullahDOĞAN It may happen when you set startDateS and startDateF to null after Where statement. Your method will be run when GetEnumrator runs. You can use ToList() to avoid this kind of problem

Comment: I dont get any error the function already check min and max if values are null dont try anythin and thats why i cant filter any data.

Comment: Make startDateS/F as DateTime, and parse straight to them..  then they can't be null ;)

Comment: Show more code, up to the point you enumerate `policiesT`

Comment: @Isparia when i add ToList() to en of my query it works fine thanks its was the scope problem.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe not an answer but in comments would be a mess. This sample works fine for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var policies = new List<Policy> {
        new Policy {StartofInsurance=new DateTime(2021,1,1)},
        new Policy {StartofInsurance=new DateTime(2021,6,21)},
        new Policy {StartofInsurance=new DateTime(2021,7,13)},
    };
    string startDateS = "01/09/2021";
    string startDateF = "07/01/2021";
    var policiesT = policies.Where(x => IsDateBetween(x.StartofInsurance, startDateS, startDateF));
    foreach (var p in policiesT)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.StartofInsurance);
    }
}

private bool IsDateBetween(DateTime date, string min, string max)
{
    bool resultMin = true;
    bool resultMax = true;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(min))
    {
        resultMin = date > Convert.ToDateTime(min);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(max))
    {
        resultMax = date < Convert.ToDateTime(max);
    }
    return resultMin && resultMax;
}

public class Policy
{
    public DateTime StartofInsurance { get; set; }
}
```

And returns the correct policy:

```
6/21/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: You can make a c#fiddle with it and comment the fiddle link if you don't want to post "not an answer"

Comment: Can you set startDateF to null and try again. I realized its work fine with both values are not null but one of the values are null both of max and min going null to function.

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks, I didn't know that. But anyway it might be the answer, I believe his problem is in culture. In his sample likely searching for Jan 9 as StartDateS but thinks  he is searching for Sep 1.

Comment: @SadullahDOĞAN, With startDateF set to null, result is 6/21 and 7/13. Which is again correct.